# WYSIWYG Editor for node titles?

Tags: wysiwyg, nodes

Is it possible to use a WYSIWYG Editor such as a CKEditor for node titles in the node creation form?

Update: Okay, so let's suppouse that I am developing a newspaper, and I want the journalists to be able to set the size of the title (i.e. if it is a very important news, they will select big font size for the title, otherwise, if it's a regular news, the title size will be medium).

Is the correct way to achieve this through Display Suite Extras, and some CSS classes?

Comment: Based upon my answer and your edited question, the user can select h1-h6 for the first piece of content in the WYSIWYG Editor

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a module for that --> https://www.drupal.org/project/html_title

An other way is probably to use the Body field (or any other) instead of the title and leave the title field as is. You could for example use the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module for this or alter your content type displays where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible as @lance mentions, but it is not advisable. The node title is designed to be plain text to be used it several parts of the site including the `<title>` tag in the `<head>`

If you want better control over the `<h1>` tag in your theme I suggest installing [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) as there is a setting in the bundled Display Suite Extras module: Page title options - Hide or manually set the page title of the "Full content" view mode.